# Почему в глобальном пространстве имен я не могу присваивать переменным значения после их объявления?

Tags: c

```
int d=5;
d=7;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //какой-то код
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выводит ошибки

```
warning: data definition has no type or storage class
24 | d=7;
  | ^
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘d’ [-Wimplicit-int]
error: redefinition of ‘d’
note: previous definition of ‘d’ was here
23 | int d=5;
```

Если же убрать `d=7;`, то все компилируется без проблем, что не так?

Comment: В С программа - это функция `main()`, в которой вызываются другие функции. Весь выполнимый код находится только в функциях. **Какой функции** принадлежит код `d=7;`?

Comment: @Harry, `int d=5` работает же

Comment: Нет, в данном случае это некорректное определение переменной `d` непонятного типа (предполагается `int`... только это было во времена K&R, если не ошибаюсь...) И `int d=5;` тоже не код, а определение переменной `d` типа `int` со значением `5`.

Comment: @Harry, на `int d=5` компилятор совершенно не ругается же, почему он не дает тогда сделать то же самое, но после объявления

Comment: Еще раз и медленно... *И `int d=5;` тоже не код, а определение переменной `d` типа `int` со значением `5`.*